# Which Regular Expression could I use to find an email address inside tags?

Tags: javascript, regex

### My problem

I have a string with an email address between tags, and I need to extract that email. For example, from here:

```
var myString = "This email for John <john@mail.com> needs to be extracted"
```

I would like to extract **john@mail.com**

### My attempt to fix

I came up with this regular expression to extract an email address from a string (it doesn't need to validate the email, just a simple regex):

```
/<\S*@\S*>/gi
```

It works fine if my string doesn't have other tags, like the previous one. But this regex fails when it finds this scenario:

```
var myString = "This bold email for John <b><john@mail.com><b/> needs to be extracted"
```

How can I improve my regex to match only the email, ignoring other tags?

P.S.: My end goal is to strip those tags out of the string (only the email tags), so I am open to other suggestions on how to do that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Trivially: change “not white space” to “not (<, >, or white space)” to make the _specific_ case pass. Anyway, the entire approach of regular expressions for email extraction is a dead horse..

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user2864740. I know there is a lot of debate about the user of regex to validate email addresses, but I couldn't think of another solution for my specific case. Do you have any suggestions of things I should look other than regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude matching the brackets, @ and whitespace chars before and after matching the `@` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^<>\s@]`

If you want to match 0 or more times, you could use `*` instead of `+`

```
<[^<>\s@]+@[^<>\s@]+>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sP2kKD/1)

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to get a perfect regular expression for matching all email addresses and only email addresses, but this should work for your case:

`/<[^<\s]*\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b[^>\s]*>/gi`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This regex did work, but I missed the explanation of why and it was too big compared with other solutions. +1 though, since it worked ;)

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working! This will just match emails more accurately. If you match "anything" followed by an `@` followed by "anything", you would match `!example@invalidurl` as a valid email address, even though it obviously isn't.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. For my use case, though I am not worried about validating the emails, I just need to extract it from the string. So a more "relaxed" rule is even better for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
"This bold email for John <b><john@mail.com><b/> needs to be extracted".match(/<\w+@\w+\.\w+/>)[0];
// <john@mail.com>
```

`\w` matches letters, numbers, and the underscore. Followed by a `+`, it matches an unbroken string of such characters.

`.` is a special character in regex so it has to be escaped.

So in the regex `\w+@\w+\.\w+`, the first `\w+` matches `john`, then `@` matches `@` of course.  The next `\w+` matches `mail`, the `\.` matches `.`, and the last `\w+` matches `com`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although, this proposed regex only finds the email address, not the tags around it. We already have another function with a regex just for emails, but my challenge here was to include the tags (<) that are only around the email.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer.  It was as simple as beginning and ending the regex with `<` and `>`.

Comment: This regex matches `____@____.____` that is not a valid address but doesn't match `first.last@example.com` or `me@localhost` that are valid. Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)